# Clarifying degrees of freedom in fixed effects model

Tags: multicollinearity, fixed-effects-model, degrees-of-freedom

I'm new to econometrics and learning about fixed effects. If I understood it correctly, we are literally including dummy variables for every observations. For example, I have a panel data of firms and if I include firm fixed effects, that means I will have dummy variables for each firm. The question I have is the problem regarding degrees of freedom. If we include dummy variables for each n firms, then that means the model has n dummy variables + some covariates, so does that mean the number of parameters exceed the number of observations?.. Then how could we run the model if so?.. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

If you have $n$ observations where each is a separate firm and you use $n$ dummy variables to identify such a firm, then yes, combined with other variables you would have too many parameters. But if you have only one row of data per firm, it doesn't make any sense to have a dummy variable per firm. If you only had the dummies, your model would find separate intercepts per each firm, i.e. it would be

$$
E[y_i] = \beta_i + \varepsilon_i
$$

so the only thing it needs to do to return predictions leading to the least error is to return $E[y_i] = y_i$, to return the data itself.

If you have fewer firms than the number of observations, but still only a few data points per each firm, you have a similar problem where you don't have enough data to reliably estimate the parameters per each firm.

So if one of those is your scenario, then you cannot include dummies per each firm in your model. To do this, you need multiple datapoints per each.

It shows that indeed if you have more parameters than datapoints, the model cannot be fitted (see also [multicollinearity](/questions/tagged/multicollinearity)). You could use a regularized model in such a scenario though.

Comment: Hi Tim! Thanks for your reply. So is it correct that we can only include fixed effects for panel data? Fixed effects in cross sectional data wouldn't make sense right?

Comment: Also your comment "so the only thing it needs to do to return predictions leading to the least error is to return []=, to return the data itself." means that the least error will basically be the intercept? which is the mean?

Comment: @chunguc1004 It has nothing to do with it. You cannot have dummies where only a single value is marked by the dummy.

Comment: I see. So let's say I have a panel data, but for some firms, I only have one observation (i.e., one firm-year observation). Then are you saying I cannot include a dummy for that one? Sorry these might be dumb questions. I'm so new to econometrics..

Comment: @chunguc1004 in the model $E[y_i]=\beta_i+\varepsilon$ you observed a single $y_i$ value and need to predict $\beta_i$ intercept such that it has the lowest squared error to predict $y_i$, $\beta_i=y_i$ has the error equal to zero.